# In the Hunger Games, what happens to the arena after the games are over?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In the Hunger Games, there have been 75 different arenas. After the tributes are done killing each other, what happens to them? And after the revolution, do they get destroyed?

Comment: The first dozen or so were actually in the _same_ arena. Namely a dilapidated sports stadium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's stated that the arenas were preserved by Panem;

> Everything is brand-new, I will be the first and only tribute to use this Launch Room. The arenas are historic sites, preserved after the Games. Popular destinations for Capitol residents to visit, to vacation. Go for a month, rewatch the Games, tour the catacombs, visit the sites where the deaths took place. You can even take part in reenactments.
>
> They say the food is excellent.
>
> <sub><sup>The Hunger Games</sup></sub>

But destroyed after the Revolution

> The questions are just beginning. The arenas have been completely
> destroyed, the memorials built, there are no more Hunger Games. But
> they teach about them at school, and the girl knows we played a role
> in them. The boy will know in a few years. How can I tell them about
> that world without frightening them to death?
>
> <sub><sup>Mockingjay</sup></sub>